# Restricting GPIOS to output-only or input-only through sysfs

Tags: linux, gpio, sysfs

I am using Ubuntu 11.10.  I have written a driver for a GPIO chip which did not have its own driver in the kernel.

I want to place a restriction on users from setting output-only pins to inputs, and vice-versa when using /sys/class/gpio.  This is because many of the GPIO's on my board are input only or output only.

I could scan for restricted GPIO numbers from within the functions gpio_direction_in(), gpio_direction_out() and gpio_request() but I think that's a bit of a hack-around.

Is there any function especially for this purpose?  I looked through the documentation for GPIOs but I couldn't see anything.

- Andrew

Comment: AFAIK, there are no straightforward ways to do this. You need to do a dirty hack of patching up the gpiolib implementation in the kernel. Instead, why can't you try this way? Don't allow the user to access it directly. Always ask them to call your program. In your program, you get the inputs and do a sanity check and allow/disallow the operations and return proper error codes to the user. BTW, which arch you use?

Comment: x86.  I will have a configuration file in my program which says which gpios are input-only and output-only.  The program accesses the /sys/class/gpio interface to change /value and /direction.  If there's no easy way to restrict manual access to the /sys/class/gpio interface, I might leave it off and just restrict access through the program. -Andrew

Comment: If I were you, I'd create a program which has the intelligence to parse the configuration file and restricts access to particular gpios. IMO, that is the easiest way you can achieve this. Other ways are there, but it is not a good idea to do something strange in the kernel space and waste time in debugging it. :)